# Refresh iOS app when In-App-Purchase purchased

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have an In App Purchase, that, when purchased, needs to reload two View Controllers in my App. however when I try to call their `ViewDidLoad()` functions, I get a bunch of `unexpected nil when opening optional` errors, even when I set a TextLabels text to `label.text = "0"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would typically post a `Notification` to which the view controllers have subscribed.  They can then refresh their state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `viewDidLoad()`, it's not your job to do. If you really wants to reload your whole app, try replacing the `rootViewController` of your main `window` which you can find in `AppDelegate`.

Or you should try different approach, use `Notification (NSNotificationCentre)` to throw and listen notifications within app and reload/update the necessary views.

Comment: helpful link - https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/using-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift-eb70cf0b60fc